# Either using a class or an id will not affect the features of this div

Tags: html, css

I just got back into css again and for some reason I can't get this div to margin-right or show background color, right off the bat..

I started off using a div with an id.

```
  #Full {
background-color: red;
margin-right: 300px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
       < div id="Full" >
```

and then I tried it with a class, ex.

```
         .Full {
background-color: red;
margin-right: 300px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
    < div class="Full" >
```

and It should be linked, here's the whole thing:

```css
.Full {
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="Full" >
        <br />
        <label> Enter Username </label>
        <input type="text" name="Username" />
        <brk />
        
        <label> Enter Password </label>
        <input type="text" name="Password" />
        <brk />
        <button class="Button1"> Enter</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Why do you have random white space in various html tags?

Comment: I suggest you to provide a Codepen link with the code you're trying

Comment: +1 to the above, but also why such a large margin right? It seems like you'd be better off setting the container width to 50% instead, for example.

Comment: those things you all mentioned really weren't included in the initial draft. Sorry. I should of made more reflective of the actual issue. I just started screwing around when it wouldn't work the first time but the failure is not contingent on any of those mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided is doing exactly as it should.
If you comment out margin-right:300px you will see the .Full div go full width.
The margin-right is pushing the right edge of the .Full box further left.

By having the body tag border turned on you can see that the .Full box stays within the bounds of the body, which tells you that the margin-right attribute is working.

```css
.Full {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

body {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Full">
    <br />
    <label> Enter Username </label>
    <input type="text" name="Username" />
    <brk />

    <label> Enter Password </label>
    <input type="text" name="Password" />
    <brk />
    <button class="Button1"> Enter</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: weird. I don't know what's going on then. Yea. I actually forgot I had that in there. I just added it to see if definiing some sort of change in position would make a difference.. : /